# *ngFor takes more then 4 seconds to load data

Tags: angular, dom, ngfor, angular-template

I have angular 7 project.

I have one generic-grid in which i am displaying data based on config.

I have one page in which grid data has 200 rows & around 20 columns

Below is sample code

```
<tr role="row" *ngFor="let objRC of filteredList | orderBy: orderFilter.orderBy : orderFilter.reverse; let idx=index; trackBy: trackByIndex;"
    [class.highlight]="objRC.highlighted">
    <td *ngIf="allowSelect">
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
            <input [id]="'check'+idx" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="objRC.selected" (change)="changeRowSelection()">
            <label [for]="'check'+idx"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td *ngFor="let objGColumn of gridColumns; let idx=index; trackBy: trackByIndex;"
        [ngSwitch]="objGColumn.type" placement="auto" [triggers]="objGColumn.popover || 'none'"
        [popover]="objRC[objGColumn.propertyKey]" [popoverTitle]="objGColumn.label | translate"
        containerClass="chiefComplaint" container="body">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'email'" [className]="'flex align-items-center ' + (objGColumn.className || '')">
            <i *ngIf="objRC[objGColumn.propertyKey]" class="fa fa-envelope mr-1">
            </i>
            <a [href]="'mailto:'+objRC[objGColumn.propertyKey]" [textContent]="objRC[objGColumn.propertyKey]"></a>
        </div>
        ....
    </td>
</tr>
```

So on based on gridColumns array columns are generated.

The issue i am facing is that after receiving data from api `*ngFor` is taking more then **4-5 seconds** to display data. Sometimes it takes even around 10 seconds. SO it takes so much time in generating **DOM**.

This is effecting app performance so much.

I even tried change-detection. Nothing seems to be working for me.

Can anyone advise me what is the solution for this?

Comment: Can you add your trackByIndex implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pagination is not an option, you are going to need to implement virtual scrolling if you want a well functioning application when doing heavy DOM 'lifting'.

You can also try implementing infinite scrolling, chunking the DOM load in smaller pieces, but once all data is rendered you might still experience performance issues depending on the size of the data set.

In Angular 7+ you can use the virtual scrolling viewport directive from the Material CDK

https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Also have a look at `ngx-datatable`

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Comment: I have generic-grid (custom grid/datatable) component. So no point in using ngx-datatable. Also in my project we don't have angular material. But we have bootstrap 4. So i can't ass angular material. it will conflict with my existing theme botstrap.

Comment: here https://hackernoon.com/naive-infinite-scroll-in-reactive-programming-using-rxjs-observables-4a605d3146e8 and https://netbasal.com/a-taste-of-angular-material-virtual-scroll-f173c5c70a1 are an infinite scroller, but I'am not sure if is some like "re-inventing the wheel". Anyway, perhafs if your "filteredList" becomes ordered yet, and not use the pipes, the behaivour improve

Comment: @AnkurAkvaliya The directive in the CDK is just a viewport, so I don't see why that would conflict with your existing theming/CSS.

Comment: Is there a way to add this directive in project without adding angular material css?

Comment: Yes, import the CDK, import the directive into your component, and have some fun. Please have a look at the docs/API https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use resolver?
Or load data when user scrolls // ngx-infinite-scroll